# Overriding abstract methods with values, a good practice?

Tags: scala

In Scala, *fields and methods belong to the same namespace* so a field can easily override a method. That's a very attractive Scala feature. For example, it allows fixing a class method to an specific reference at some point of a classes hierarchy:

```
abstract class AC { def x: Int }
class C extends AC { override val x = 10 }
```

Suppose there is a second `Base`'s attribute calculated form `x`:

```
abstract class AC { def x: Int; val y: Int = x*2 }
class C extends AC { override val x = 10 }

val v = (new C).y
```

One could expect `v` value to be `20` however it is `0`. **Ok, what is happening is that `AC` constructor is being called before `C`'s, hence, `x` (which is now an attribute) isn't set at that point yet** and the constructor uses the default value for integers (I may be wrong).

What strikes me is that with:

```
class C extends AC { override def x = 10 }

val v = (new C).y
```

`v` equals 20.

I have a hunch that the difference comes from the fact that methods get resolved in a different way than values. Can somebody give an explanation for the behaviour difference? more details on how Scala constructors work? 
Wouldn't it be more coherent to have the same behaviour in both cases?

**Concerning the question's title:** Isn't it hazardous to override methods as values? Some client code could do that for a library class without noticing that dependant attributes could get invalid values thus generating bugs.

Comment: I think the better practice would be to make `y` lazy or a def when it references something that may be overridden. Though I'm not sure why the second initialization has problems. It's hard to find anything in the spec about how overriding a def with a val is handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields of the superclass are instantiated before the fields of the subclass. So given

```
abstract class AC {
  def x: Int
  val y: Int = x * 2
}

class C extends AC {
  override val x = 10
}
```

`new C` will first instantiate the fields of `AC`, in this case `y` and then the fields of `C`, i.e., `x`. Because `Int` values are `0` before initialization, `y = x * 2` will be `0`.

Now, if you override `x` as a method (`def`), then `C` has no fields to be initialized and `y = x * 2` calls the method `x` which returns `10`, hence `y` takes the value `20`. **Update:** To make it clear, methods do not belong to a single instance, but are shared among all instances of the same class. Hence, the method `x` is created at compile time not when the instance of `C` is created.

The thing I consider dangerous here is that `y` in `AC` is a `val`; doing so forces `y` to be instantiated before the fields of the subclasses are initialized, forming a potential forward reference. If you want to refrain from implementing `y` as a method, you can implement it as a `lazy val`, meaning it is evaluated exactly once, namely on its first use, in this case only after the object is fully instantiated.

```
abstract class AC {
  def x: Int
  lazy val y: Int = x * 2
}

class C extends AC {
  override val x = 10
}

println((new C).y) // prints 20, because y is initialized on its first use
```

By the way: The same problem occurs if you override a `val` as a `val`.

```
class AB {
  val x = 10
  val y = x * 2
}
class B extends AB {
  override val x = 4
}

println((new B).y) // prints 0, because the overridden `x` is not yet initialized
```

Comment: As described in my question, I´d expect `y` to be 0 when `x` is an attribute; What surprises me is that `y` isn't 0 when `x` is a method. As I can understand from your answer when `y` is instantiated by `AC`'s constructor `x` method is called, being its implementation the provided by the subclass.

Comment: Your edit tells me I might be misexpressing: Of course methods do not belong to a single instance, that isn't the question here. It is that, as far as I currently understand, the fact of `y` getting the right value when `x` is a method may be explained by the fact that `AC` constructor is calling to `C` (CLASS) implementation of `x`.

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo Yes, when the method `x` is called, the right implementation is chosen based on the runtime type, here it is an instance of `C`. Albeit the example is for c++, the Wikipedia page on [VTable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) has a nice example of a possible memory layout. I assume the general idea is also true for Scala. Also note that Scala creates a getter-method for every `val`, making overriding `def` as `val` possible. Does this answer the question?